# LINQ not submitting changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm using C# and LINQ to SQL

I'm issuing the following command:

```
User cu = CurrentUser;

Post newPost = new Post
{
    CreateDate = now,
    ModifyDate = now,
    User = cu,
    ModifyUser = cu,
    Text = text,
    Title = title,
    Thread = t,
    ResponseToPostID = null
};

this.AppManager.DB.Posts.InsertOnSubmit(newPost);
this.AppManager.DB.SubmitChanges();
```

But absolutely no changes are being issued.

The Posts table was created with this SQL exactly:

```
CREATE TABLE forum.Posts (
    PostID bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    ThreadID bigint NOT NULL,
    ResponseToPostID bigint NULL,
    UserID bigint NOT NULL,
    Title varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    [Text] text NOT NULL,
    CreateDate datetime NOT NULL,
    ModifyDate datetime NOT NULL,
    ModifyUserID bigint NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Posts PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PostID ASC)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE forum.Posts
    WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Posts_Threads
    FOREIGN KEY (ThreadID)
    REFERENCES forum.Threads (ThreadID)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE forum.Posts
    WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Posts_Users
    FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
    REFERENCES dbo.Users (UserID)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE forum.Posts
    WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Posts_ModifyUsers
    FOREIGN KEY (ModifyUserID)
    REFERENCES dbo.Users (UserID)
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
GO
```

So, if I set a breakpoing just before the SubmitChanges call and check `this.AppManager.DB.GetChangeSet();` in a watch, it says: {Inserts: 0, Updates: 0, Deletes: 0}

Which should clearly not be the case.

My generated Post object looks like this (about):

```
[Column(Storage="_PostID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="BigInt NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
public long PostID[...]

[Column(Storage="_ThreadID", DbType="BigInt NOT NULL")]
public long ThreadID[...]

[Column(Storage="_ResponseToPostID", DbType="BigInt")]
public System.Nullable<long> ResponseToPostID[...]

[Column(Storage="_UserID", DbType="BigInt NOT NULL")]
public long UserID[...]

[Column(Storage="_Title", DbType="VarChar(60) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
public string Title[...]

[Column(Storage="_Text", DbType="Text NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
public string Text[...]

[Column(Storage="_CreateDate", DbType="DateTime NOT NULL")]
public System.DateTime CreateDate[...]

[Column(Storage="_ModifyDate", DbType="DateTime NOT NULL")]
public System.DateTime ModifyDate[...]

[Column(Storage="_ModifyUserID", DbType="BigInt")]
public System.Nullable<long> ModifyUserID[...]

[Association(Name="User_Post", Storage="_User", ThisKey="ModifyUserID", OtherKey="UserID", IsForeignKey=true)]
public User ModifyUser[...]

[Association(Name="User_Post1", Storage="_User1", ThisKey="UserID", OtherKey="UserID", IsForeignKey=true, DeleteOnNull=true, DeleteRule="CASCADE")]
public User User[...]

[Association(Name="Thread_Post", Storage="_Thread", ThisKey="ThreadID", OtherKey="ThreadID", IsForeignKey=true, DeleteOnNull=true, DeleteRule="CASCADE")]
public Thread Thread[...]
```

And, in my base controller:

```
protected LanLordzApplicationManager AppManager
{
    get
    {
        return (LanLordzApplicationManager)(Session["Application"] ?? new LanLordzApplicationManager(Server.MapPath("~/")));
    }
}

protected User CurrentUser
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["UserID"] == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.AppManager.GetUserByUserID((long)Session["UserID"]);
        }
    }
    set
    {
        Session["UserID"] = value.UserID;
    }
}

// In LanLordzAppManager:

public LanLordzDataContext DB
{
    get
    {
        return this.db;
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error lies in the following line:

```
return (LanLordzApplicationManager)(Session["Application"] ?? 
  new LanLordzApplicationManager(Server.MapPath("~/")));
```

Logic seems to indicate you should add the ApplicationManager to the Session.

Comment: You are right.  How could I be so blind? Thanks,  I guess that's what I get for using a shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks like DB is a property on AppManager, could you show the code for the property accessors?  Your code looks ok to me so the only thing that I can think is that a new data context is being generated via the accessor.

Comment: Updated with my AppManager accessor.

Comment: Please update your question with the DB accessor code on the AppManager also.

Comment: +1, You were right.  I gave the answer to leppie, 'cause he found the line.